# Swift iOS sometimes not detecting touches

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uibutton, touch

I am creating an iOS keyboard extension with `UIInputViewController`, and using `UIButton` for each key. I have two issues:

1. Sometimes buttons don't detect touches.
2. Touches at the edges of the screen are recognized with a delay.

I assume first one happens when I type too fast, or when touch area is too big (bigger than the button). I tried using different methods of detecting touch (`button target`, `touchesBegan`, `touchesEnded`, `UITapGestureRecognizer`) and all have the same issue.

I assume second happens because of the iOS edge false touch rejection. I tried changing `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` but it had no effect.

Please help.

Comment: do you have `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` implemented anywhere?

Comment: @Chameleon Nope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Turns out I was playing a quick animation on the UIButton press, so I had to set `.allowUserInteraction` in the animation options.
2. I used `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` with `minimumPressDuration = 0` which, for some reason, is always instant even at the edges.